# Are Muslims allowed to nickname each other?

Tags: hadith-interpretation

I remember one hadith mentioned that our beloved Prophet Mohammad (pbu) went masjid to find Ali when he was lying and sleeping in the masjid while lots dust on his body. Our Prophet(pbu) dusted sand off Ali's body and saying "
Get up! Father of Sand..."

I remember one should not call nickname but strictly one's name in Islam and its a sin to do so. I wonder what is the explanation of this hadith and in term of allowing one to call other in some other name that is not consider...offensive?

Please provide haidth / quran reference with your answer, no opinions only answer please, inshaAllah.

Comment: http://www.classicalislamgroup.com/index.php?view=tafseer/s49-v11 assalam u alaikum dear brother I think this link may help you.......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may not be the ideal answer but it's a little too much to put in a comment so if someone can better it, please do so.

Note these names:

1. The best man after the noble prophet (S) was called "Abu Bakr"
2. The popular sahaabah who was like the shadow of the prophet (s) was called "Abu Huraira" - father of cats
3. Uthmaan Bin Affaan , the 3rd Khaleefah was called "Zun-noorain" The owner of 2 lights (he married two of the prophet's (s) daughters (of course one after the other).
4. Muadh was "Ibn Jabal" - the son of the mountain :)

So these are names called out with respect. They are not meant to insult or slander anyone. In Arabic we called them "Kunya" and this is not necessarily *Islamic* but it's the tradition of that land.

So a nickname called out to insult someone is different.

And Allaah knows best.

Comment: Jazaklahir for the answer. I guess its really close to a legit answer, since so many names examples are referenced

Answer (score 0):

I want to let everyone know that it not haram that you give some one nick name, but also the nick name should not be haram like bad names or UN wanted names, if we back to the time of our prophet Mohamed peace be upon him, we find that most of the friends of our prophet have nick names, so from this I say that its not haram and  Allah know the best...

Comment: Jazaklahir for the answer. But your answer is rather a duplication of itsols, inshaAllah, please promote the website if you have more exact reference and as an extension, improve or different answer than the BEST answer selected above, isnhaAllah.

Comment: okay brother  i will do my best in shaa allah  in  next time thanks for your support  and may allah  reward you blessing   jazak allah khairian

Answer (score 0):

The prohibition is not about the use of nicknames in general, but specifically about bad names which hurt people's feelings.  This is not the case for the nickname used in the hadith, so the prohibition does not apply.